# CS50 Runoff program is working but check50 says it doesn't

Tags: c, cs50

So basically my program is supposed to make some sort of a runoff election( Here you can see what is it: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/3/runoff/). I needed to implement 6 functions in order to do it and I did it. My program works perfectly fine but check50 says that function print_winner doesn't work ( though it only costs 4/24 possible points). This function must print the candidate of an election if he has a majority of all votes (>50%). The error says just "print_winner must print name when someone has a majority, print_winner did not print winner of election" and 3 more of such errors.

Here is the whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX 9

typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
    bool eliminated;
}
candidate;

candidate candidates[MAX];

int voter_count;
int candidate_count;
int preferences[MAX][MAX];
float winner_vote;

//void check_preference(void);
bool is_tie(int min);
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name);
bool print_winner(void);
void tabulate(void);
int find_min(void);
void eliminate(int min);


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    candidate_count = argc - 1;

    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count ; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
        candidates[i].eliminated = false;
    }

    voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    winner_vote = voter_count / 2;
    int integer = winner_vote;

    if (winner_vote == integer)
    {
        winner_vote++;
    }
    else
    {
        winner_vote = ceil(winner_vote);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {


            string name = get_string("Rank %i ", j + 1);

            if (!vote(i, j, name))

            {
                printf("Invalid vote\n");
                j--;
            }

        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    //check_preference();

    while (true)
    {
        tabulate();

        if (print_winner())
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (is_tie(find_min()))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            eliminate(find_min());
        }

    }
}


void eliminate(int min)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (min == candidates[i].votes)
        {
            candidates[i].eliminated = true;
        }
    }

}




int find_min(void)
{
    int min = MAX;
    for (int i = 1; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (min > candidates[i].votes)
        {
            min = candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }

    return min;



}


bool is_tie(int min)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (min == candidates[i].votes)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}




bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)
{
    bool exist = false;



    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[preferences[voter][i]].name) == 0 && rank > 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0)
        {

            preferences[voter][rank] = i;
            exist = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return exist;
}







bool print_winner(void)
{
    // candidate candidateHolder;
    for (int f = 0; f < candidate_count; f++)
    {
        //candidateHolder = candidates[f];
        if (candidates[f].votes >= winner_vote)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[f].name);
            return 1;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}

void tabulate(void)
{
    int check = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        if (!candidates[preferences[i][check]].eliminated)
        {
            candidates[preferences[i][check]].votes++;
            check = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            check++;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the function that creates error:

```
bool print_winner(void)
{
    // candidate candidateHolder;
    for (int f = 0; f < candidate_count; f++)
    {
        //candidateHolder = candidates[f];
        if (candidates[f].votes >= winner_vote)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[f].name);
            return 1;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if (winner_vote == integer) is always true since you set integer to winner_vote in the previous line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I declared winner_vote in the function and it worked

The problem is it puts my function inside of their code. So winner_vote variable is undefined there. There's nothing to do with 1 or 0. By the way, 1 in a bool means true and 0 means false. Why I put them instead of words because the explanation video said return 1 if ... and return 0 if ... I thought maybe this will change something.

And my other problem was that i forgot to mark my answer as a correct one. So people are still trying to help

Answer (score 0):

looks like you forgot 
"If any candidate has a majority (more than 50%) of the first preference votes, that candidate is declared the winner of the election."

Comment: Everything was fine with code but check50 was using these functions independently from my code, that's why it didn't know what is winner_vote in the function

Answer (score 0):

The variables that are used to determine **winner_vote** (aka) the majority have to be floats i.e voter_count / 2.  Integers will not work if you have to divide 3/2 or 5/2

Additionally, in order to win the majority, the candidates[f].votes has to be > the majority, not >=. In the latter instance a tie between two candidates would be printed in the print_winner function. Ties are determined in the is_tie function later in the code.

Bool functions must have a return value of true or false.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your printer_winner will return a 0 or a 1.
check50 expects a TRUE or FALSE.

a simple statement will fix that for you:

> printf("%s", winner_vote ? "true" : "false");

This will convert the 1 and 0 to TRUE ans FALSE. 
Hope this helps. First time programmer here ;).

Answer (score 0):

You could init two global variables one integer, other  floating(`int max;
float pmax;`) and delete your unnecessary code and variables in the beginning.

Below your function content:

```
bool print_winner(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (max < candidates[i].votes)
        {
            max = candidates[i].votes;
            pmax = ((float) max /(float) voter_count);
            if (pmax > 0.5)
            {
                printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool print_winner(void)
{
    int maj = voter_count / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes > maj)
        {
            printf("%s\n",candidates[i].name);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

Why don't you try this instead??
Why do you return an int when type specified is bool?

Comment: ints can be coinverted to bools, and bools can be converted to ints (well, 0 and 1, but that still fits in an int). https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/637ffd36f35dcb08 (you can edit that and flip the 1 to a 0. Conversion problems only start happening for numbers over 1 - I think all non-zero values are true. Tbf, that's used for pointer checks, and can be used for other if statements)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this as an alternative as well

```
 bool won = print_winner();
    if (won)
    {
        break;
    }

    // Eliminate last-place candidates
    int min = find_min();
    bool tie = is_tie(min);

    // If tie, everyone wins
    if (tie)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
            {
                printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Print the winner of the election, if there is one
bool print_winner(void)
{
    int won;
    win_score = voter_count / 2;
    won = win_score;
    if (win_score == won)
    {
        win_score++;
    }
    else
    {
        win_score = ceil(win_score);
    }
    //  for each candidate sum the 1st choices
    // if candidates[i].votes > voters / 2; win then quit
    // else call find_min then is_tie if so everyone wins else eliminate min
    // then tabulate next rank to candidate/s
    for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
    {
        if (candidates[j].votes >= win_score)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[j].name);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add extra explanation to ecplane your code snippet